# No pressure in secondary

Tags: yeast, secondary-fermentation, ale

I have a problem with an ale kit I've brewed and kegged. I have done primary with a s04 yeast and its been in secondary for about 5 days and I've checked it this morning and its not built up pressure. I have added co2 this morning and its holding pressure.

Is this normal with the yeast, its the first time I have added anything but the stuff you get with the kits.

I didn't know if it's possible the yeast all fell out of suspension in primary so there wasn't enough to pressurise?

Should I put it into another keg with more priming sugar?

I was going to have a little taste tonight to check it's still OK. I'm hoping it is...

Comment: If this is a serving keg you are using, why not just force carbonate it? I never prime my kegs.

Comment: So your not actually in a second fermentor you are talking about being in a keg?

Comment: Did you perhaps put the keg in a cold place?

Comment: I have checked the screw cap with starsan and have found a leak on the gasket. Thats why its escaping. I have just emptied a kingkeg so should i rack it into that? Ive put it back into my warm room and will be there for a few days then cool it again. Im a bit annoyed its happened as i wanted it ready for next weekend really as its my birthday!

Answer (score 1):

There is always plenty of yeast in suspension unless one did an extended cold store in secondary.  Fermentis S04 is a pretty reliable yeast.

I wouldn't add more priming sugar yet.  I'd make sure the keg is warm enough and give it more time.  Fermentis S04 is a pretty reliable yeast, but it can be finicky to dropping temps and alcohol.  5 days is a little short to expect carbonation from this yeast if the first things I mentioned haven't been handled.

Lastly, be totally sure your keg is holding pressure.  If you apply pressure and check it immediately that doesn't indicate a small leak that takes overnight to bleed out.  Spry all fittings with some foaming sanitizer to be certain no gas is escaping.  The bleed the excess CO2 as too much pressure will keep the yeast from carbonating as well.